# Variables in HTML with gulp

Tags: html, gulp

Is there a way to replace variables with gulp inside HTML? In my case, I have development HTML files where are paths for images, for e.g. `/assets/img/*.jpg`, but in production file I need those paths replace with ones which the CMS generates after file uploads. They are completely different and there isn't logic in folder names for e.g. `/12365/586/*.jpg`.

Im looking for:

- gulp task to replace and generate HTML for development
- gulp task to replace and generate HTML for production

Dev HTML

```
variable_name_dev = "/assets/img"
variable_name_prod = "/12365/5698"

<img src="variable_name/bg.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
```

Generated Dev HTML

```
<img src="/assets/img/bg.jpg" alt="Smiley face">
```

Generated Production HTML

```
<img src="/12365/5698" alt="Smiley face">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [gulp-inline-image-path](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-inline-image-path/)? Or I've used [gulp-token-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-token-replace/) for similar scenarios.

Comment: `gulp-token-replace` works like a charm